# Detect Inventory change on Magento2 triggered by API

Tags: magento2, event-observer, stock, magento2.2

I'm working on a module for keeping track of inventory changes on orders, admin variation, api calls.

I'm using the event `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after` which works fine on 2.2 but it seems to work only on the admin side. No luck on frontend orders.

Should it supposed to be dispatched whenever a stock item change is detected? What about api?

Comment: Do you have enterprise or open source version ?

Comment: CE thanks, would it be different on Enterprise?

Comment: Your module should be able to detect which "part" of magento changes the stock ? (for e.g. an order, admin or api)... or just behave as a monitor to  stock changes ? (adding and subtract)

Comment: On enterprise there is a module specific for inventory, you can based on this.

Comment: Can you please show me your `events.xml`?

Comment: @AlexConstantinescu I should be able to detect which part of magento changes the stock and the variation

Comment: thanks @FranckGarnier, is the enterprise module available to public?

Comment: @AntonioPedicini hi did you find any solution?